# NRF24l01 with Atmega 32u4 and internal clock

Tags: nrf24l01+, atmega32u4, oscillator-clock

Will the nrf24l01 work with the Atmega 32u4 if I am using the 32u4's internal clock, or must I have an external clock source?

Comment: Knowing the interface between nrf24l01+ and Atmega32U4 is also answer to your question. And even with using asynchronous serial it should be possible (but might be less reliable sometimes)

Comment: Connecting to nrf24 via    CE, CSN, SCK, MOSI, MISO   -    I have the nrf24 working fine on my Pro Micro, now trying it on my custom pcb where I do not use an external oscillator.  My custom pcb works fine other wise, including the SPI as I have another device working on the SPI.  Just not working with the nrf24.

Comment: And SPI is **synchronous** interface, so there is a master sending `CLK` signal to clock data to selected slave

Comment: Correction,  My other device is connected via I2C,  not SPI.  But I am programming the 32u4 via SPI.

Comment: Without at least schematics, test scenarios and so on (what works or not works and where), it's hard to guess.

Comment: Should be just fine. I2C and SPI don't care about at what speed the MCU runs. Only things like UART sometimes require a more stable clock source, like a crystal, instead of the internal RC oscillator.

Comment: I found a mistake on my custom pcb,  I wanted CE as pin4 and CSN as pin5, but I mistakenly put them to pins 38 & 39 on the chip which are A4 and A5. Any issue having analog pins as CE and CSN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask a yes/no question, to which the answer is yes, nRF24L01 as a serial peripheral device will work as well as if you had used an Arduino UNO or any other microcontroller, provided the SPI bus is correctly initialized.

Generally you want the following in the `setup()` part of your sketch/program:

```
  pinMode(CE_pin, OUTPUT);//chip enable set as output
  pinMode(CSN_pin, OUTPUT);//chip select pin as output
  pinMode(MOSI_pin, OUTPUT);//SPI data out
  pinMode(MISO_pin, INPUT); //SPI data in
  pinMode(SCK_pin, OUTPUT);//SPI clock out

  digitalWrite(CSN_pin, HIGH);//SPI idle
  digitalWrite(CE_pin, LOW);

  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);//SPI Most Significant Bit First
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);// Mode 0 Rising edge of data, keep clock low
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV2);//Run the data in at 16MHz/2 - 8MHz
  SPI.begin();//start up SPI library
```